# PHP if condition not evaluating correctly

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having an issue with some PHP code. Basically I have an array of id values, `$challengeIDs`, and a value `$number` which stores the current location in this array (it affects which page is loaded into the body). I want to check that I haven't reached the end of the array before I move to the next ID value.

```
if (($number+1) < (count($challengeIDs)-1)) {
    $n = $number+1;
    echo "window.location = './challenge.php?n={$n}';";
} else {
    $_SESSION['n'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['playlist'] = "";
    echo "window.location = './index.php';";            
}
echo "});}</script>";
```

I've put a `console.log()` statement immediately above this snippet which reports that the value of `$number` is 1 and `count($challengeIDs)` is 4. But for some reason the page is going to index.php rather than going to the next page in the list. It may be elsewhere in the code, but any ideas? Anything suggestions are gratefully received :)

EDIT:
Here is the console output. The values are output the line before this snippet, and the page changes according to the value. It works no problem from page 1 (n=0) to page 2 (n=1), but fails and goes to index.php going to page 3 (n=2).

[image: Screenshot of console]

SOLUTION:
Ended up working it out - sorry guys, it wasn't related to this code at all. There was a check elsewhere which was incorrectly resetting the values based on a GET parameter.

Comment: Why are you combining PHP and JS in this manner? You should be using PHP's header function.

Comment: `console.log()` is JS not PHP?!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm doing that because I need the script to take some values from within the session cookie/sessionStorage. I'm building the whole script on the page using PHP - I couldn't find another workaround in this case.

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah but it's the text argument within a PHP echo statement....I'm printing the script to the page with PHP

Comment: Then you should use AJAX.

Comment: @JayBlanchard As far as Ive been able to tell, I can't use ajax, jquery or js to directly access the Session cookie or the sessionStorage without more POST requests. This seemed like the simplest solution, and it's working for the purpose, just this weird little bug

Comment: Try console.log with number+1 and see what do you get?

Comment: My *spidey sense* tells me that your logic and division of labor between the client-side and server-side is wrong.

Comment: Try to console ($number+1) and (count($challengeIDs)-1) values, you'll get to know what is the issue.

Comment: @SameerJain I did that when I was tracing it down in case it was a type mismatch, but they show correctly :(

Comment: @Aparna I did that when I was tracing it down in case it was a type mismatch, but they show correctly :(

Comment: @JayBlanchard Quite possibly, but I'm a web noob doing a rush job for a friend before I go on holiday. Just has to work...

Comment: then you can echo those values in your else condition and put an exit there to check the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid but I think you may be using wrong the if clause
In the code I can see

```
if (($number+1) < (count($challengeIDs)-1)) {
```

and you wrote that

> count($challengeIDs) is 4.

So when page is 3 (n=2) where there is your problem, it goes to the else clause because

```
if (($number+1) < (count($challengeIDs)-1))
```

means

```
if ((2+1) < (4-1))
```

and 3 is not lesser than 3. So change the if clause.

Comment: Because the PHP was printing to the page not actually doing the redirect itself, this is what is meant to happen. When it is on page 3, the javascript save() function being created in the code shown is written to take it to the index.php, not to the next challenge but this only happens when the save function is called, not when the PHP executes.
I've solved the issue now. Thanks for trying to help - not a stupid point at all - I spent a long time checking and double checking those values in case I was getting confused, or the execution times for the php/js were happening at unexpected times